# Unit Test to determine that Action is returning correct View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

How can you test that an action method you have like so will return the correct view because Viewname is an empty string?  Should I even bother testing this? I'm not sure how many unit tests to do, I'm thinking you could create a lot of unit tests!

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}


[TestMethod]
public void DetermineIndexReturnsCorrectView()
{
     HomeController controller = new HomeController();

     ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

     //****result.ViewName is empty!!!!***//
     Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [MvcContrib Testhelpers](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper). Nice examples there as well

Answer (score 7):

Test the type of the result.

```
//Act
var result = controller.Create();

//Assert
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
```

Then write separate tests for RedirectToRouteResult cases and handle exception cases as well and you're set.

Comment: And test the contents of RouteValues?

Comment: For cases of redirection yes, I typically do something like....                      Assert.That(result.RouteValues["action"], Is.EqualTo("Index"),
                        "RedirectResult does not contain a routevalue with an action of Index");

Answer (score 6):

Inside your controller action you didn't specify view name so it's an empty string. In that case MVC takes view name to be same as action name.

> Should I even bother testing this?

You should definitely test this.

`Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, result.ViewName);`

> I'm not sure how many unit tests to
>   do...

As many as you can. Think of it is an investment which can save you a lot of time later.

Comment: Thanks @frennky for your response. I'm using MVC4 and was trying to work out the cause of this problem. Manually typing in the view name confirmed your response was correct.

Comment: it's an overly naive assumption that unit tests will (always) save you time later. Research is not in the favour of that statement http://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf

Answer (score 2):

An example of the MvcContrib TestHelpers code would be something like

```
var result = _testController.Details("ref").AssertViewRendered().ForView("TestDetails");
```

This tests that _testController Details method is returning the view "TestDetails"

Answer (score 2):

If you have a view like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

the `ViewName` property will take the default value `""`. You need to specify the `ViewName` like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

to solve it.